# Silverlight Datagrid edit per row

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Is there a way to edit a silverlight 3 DataGrid by row and not by cell?

I would like a way to turn off the cell editing functionality and set the whole row in edit state (that should also display the CellEditingTemplate templates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question i can say that this functionality is not supported for silverlight 3. 
Not sure if this is implemented for later versions though.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [RowDetailsTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for this.

You can have your customized UI for row editing in this RowDetailsTemplate.